# Can a ServerSocket and a Socket use one same port?

Tags: sockets, port, tuples, serversocket

Now I want to use a serversocket to listen port x, in the same time I want to use the port x to establish a socket to other serversocket, that means there is a serversocket and a socket will use one same port, is that possible?
I know for socket, it is four tuple, one port can have multiple socket, but for a socket and serversocket?
thank you for your attention!

Comment: What happens when you *try* it?

Comment: Why? There are few if any valid reasons to used a fixed outbound port number.

Comment: if I create one serversocket and a socket with one port <br>
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(2000);//to listen the request of connection<br>
Socket server = new Socket(localIP,2000; DistantIP, DistantPort); //use the same port to connect the distant<br>
but there is an exception "Already in use"?<br>

As socket is four tuple, I think there should not be this problem , or there is some other solution?

Comment: @seaguest: Why do you think there should not be this problem? What keeps the entire 4-tuple from being the same? If the computer only has one IP address and uses the same port for both, what stops the computer from connecting out to a remote IP/port that precisely matches an inbound connection at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to understand your question because it's not clear when you say "port" whether you mean source port or destination port.

If your question is, "Can I accept inbound connections *on* port X and also make outbound connections *to* port X?" The answer is yes. (You can *bind to* and *connect to* the same port.)

If your question is, "Can I listen *on* port X and also make outbound connections *from* port X?" The answer is no -- unless you use two different local IP addresses. For TCP on a single IP address, you can only bind to the port once. If you bind to listen, from then on, the port is reserved for the incoming connections you will accept -- you cannot bind to it again to make outgoing connections *from* it.

Comment: if I create one serversocket and a socket with one port
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(2000);//to listen the request of connection
Socket server = new Socket(localIP,2000; DistantIP, DistantPort); //use the same port to connect the distant
but there is an exception "Already inuse"?
However I have seen some ptograms use the same port to listen and communicate, maybe I misunderstood it, is it really impossible?

Comment: A program can listen on port 8080 and also connect outbound connections *to* port 8080. A program cannot listen on port 8080 and also make outbound connections *from* port 8080.

Comment: "*Can I listen on port X and also make outbound connections from port X?*" - with the [SO_REUSEPORT flag](https://lwn.net/Articles/542629/), this is actually possible